# Datagridview showing different results from the query builder

Tags: c#, sql

I have an issue where the data returned by the query builder is different to the data displayed by the query builder or data preview on Visual Studio 2015.

My SQL Query is :

```
SELECT        
    COUNT(Date_Order_Despatched.[Order Number]) AS Orders, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(DAY, @day * (DATEDIFF(day, @fromdate, Date_Order_Despatched.[Date Order Desptached]) / @day), @fromdate), 20) AS DateDespatched, 
    (CASE 
         WHEN scheme.waopheadm.courier_serv_name = 'Generic Next Day' 
            THEN 'B2B' 
         WHEN scheme.waopheadm.courier_serv_name = 'Generic Pallet Service' 
            THEN 'B2B' 
         ELSE 'B2C' 
     END) AS B2BorB2C
FROM 
    Date_Order_Despatched 
INNER JOIN
    scheme.waopheadm ON Date_Order_Despatched.[Order Number] = scheme.waopheadm.orderkey
WHERE
    (Date_Order_Despatched.[Date Order Desptached] BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate)
GROUP BY 
    (DATEADD(DAY, @day * (DATEDIFF(day, @fromdate, Date_Order_Despatched.[Date Order Desptached]) / @day), @fromdate)), 
    (CASE WHEN scheme.waopheadm.courier_serv_name = 'Generic Next Day' THEN 'B2B' WHEN scheme.waopheadm.courier_serv_name = 'Generic Pallet Service' THEN 'B2B' ELSE 'B2C' END)
```

This is the results I get from this query are:

```
989 2016-08-01  B2C
575 2016-08-06  B2C
432 2016-08-11  B2C
678 2016-08-16  B2C
870 2016-08-21  B2C
840 2016-08-26  B2C
678 2016-08-31  B2C
3   2016-09-05  B2C
```

This is the results as per the datagridview with the same parameters :

```
257 01/08/2016  
240 02/08/2016  
147 03/08/2016  
195 04/08/2016  
150 05/08/2016  
193 08/08/2016  
165 09/08/2016  
217 10/08/2016  
164 11/08/2016  
128 12/08/2016  
140 15/08/2016  
186 16/08/2016  
140 17/08/2016  
169 18/08/2016  
183 19/08/2016  
223 22/08/2016  
205 23/08/2016  
181 24/08/2016  
261 25/08/2016  
255 26/08/2016  
333 29/08/2016  
252 30/08/2016  
237 31/08/2016  
211 01/09/2016  
230 02/09/2016  
3   05/09/2016
```

Any help here is be appreciated.

c# code to bind data :

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
                    {
                        sqlConnection.Open();
                        cs3liveDataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;
                        order_Despatched_ScreeTableAdapter.FillChartPerXDaysAll(cs3liveDataSet.Order_Despatched_Scree,Convert.ToInt16(otherNumericUpDown.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(fromDateTimePicker.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(toDateTimePicker.Value), B2BOrB2CComboBox.Text);
                        OrderDataGridView.Refresh();
                        OrderDataGridView.Visible = true;
                        OrderDataGridView.Enabled = true;
                        sqlConnection.Close();
                    }
```

I have redone the code so that it pulls from the sqlcommand :

```sql
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
                    {
                        sqlConnection.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT COUNT([Order Number]) AS Orders, CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(DAY, (5*(DATEDIFF(day, @FROMDATE, [Date Order Desptached])/5)), @FROMDATE), 103) AS DateDespatched FROM Date_Order_Despatched WHERE ([Date Order Desptached] BETWEEN @FROMDATE AND @TODATE) GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(DAY, (5*(DATEDIFF(day, @FROMDATE, [Date Order Desptached])/5)),@FROMDATE), 103)", sqlConnection);
                        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DAY",otherNumericUpDown.Value);//@DAY
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FROMDATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fromDateTimePicker.Value;//@FROMDATE
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TODATE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = toDateTimePicker.Value;//@TODATE
                        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        SDA.Fill(dt);
                        OrderDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
                        OrderDataGridView.Refresh();                     
                        OrderDataGridView.Enabled = true;
                        sqlConnection.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: it's the same result just different date format

Comment: It is not the same result.. The build groups every 5 days as per the query. However the datagridview shows everyday. not grouping the x number of days. I have played with the date format, and that is not making any difference. Main issue is that i need the datagrid to return the x number of days grouping as the query builder.

Comment: Also please note that i have used both bound data column and unbound data columns and i am getting the same issue. I have even tried to convert date to string to prevent the data format being incorrect.

Comment: Can you show the C# part of your code please

Comment: pls edit your question and include whole C# part where you execute SQL query and bind it to DataGridView

Comment: Hi ChenChi, I have added the c# code.

Comment: It seems you are using `Typed DataSet` and `sqlConnection` seems to be useless. Can you show us the query that you are using behind `order_Despatched_ScreeTableAdapter.FillChartPerXDaysAll` method

Comment: Hi sallushan. Please note that the query has been posted already in the original question. This method has worked for every query with datagrids except for this query that displays per x days grouping...

Comment: I have looked further into this issue. When i hard code "@day" in my sql query to 5, then the datagrid works fine. but if i use "@day" as a parameter, then datagrid is incorrect.... all other parameters are working.

Comment: I have figured it out. On the sql query, i had to convert the @days to varchar.